# Odoo8 Postgres Error

Tags: python, macos, postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

i want to install odoo on mac osx. I already installed all python dependencies, and the server is starting. 
But than i get this error:

```
   2015-08-27 08:38:49,758 44860 ERROR None werkzeug: Error on request:
      File "/Users/USER/Documents/odoo/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 522, in borrow
        result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
    OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Postgres is running an connection with my user is working

Comment: When do you get this error? When trying to log in?

Comment: If i go to localhost:8069 i get in the browser an error with internal server error. And get this error in the logs.
It's before the login screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed mine from the `.deb` package, so this advice is guesswork from reading your error and the source.

The best clue is from the PG driver; `no password supplied`. I've checked my own `openerp-server.conf` and it says:

```
db_host = False
db_port = False
db_user = odoo
db_password = False
```

I'm guessing part of the package install "did something" to either postgres or the postgres user to allow passwordless access - I've looked in my `pg_hba.conf` file and I can't see anything out of the ordinary. I've also looked in `pg_shadow` and the `odoo` user in there is passwordless. There is however a non-login system user called `odoo`. I suspect this has something to do with it.

I would try putting your full database credentials into `openerp-server.conf`. If that doesn't work you might consider putting a line in your `pg_hba.conf` like

```
local    odoo_db    odoo_user    [no address]    trust
```

for testing. I wouldn't recommend this for a production environment though.